# Group time-series observations dynamically in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have time-series data of five days, formatted as `xts` object. The data is generated as:

```
library(xts)
Sys.setenv(TZ="Asia/Kolkata")
seq <- timeBasedSeq('2015-06-01/2015-06-05 23')
z <- xts(1:length(seq),seq)
```

Now, I want to group the data with similar timestamps (only **H:M:S**), dynamically  in a for loop and then perform required operation on each group. Here, I am facing two problems:

1. How should I run for loop over `xts` time indices. I mean to say, can I traverse using `minutes` of `xts` object?
2. How should I group the observations with similar time stamps and perform the required operation. For example, find all the observations at 11 A.M. of all 5 days and compute regression coefficients. Is there any defined function to group time-series observations dynamically?

In all these operations, I don't want to lose `xts` index.

Comment: To find all obs at 11 a.m. and preserve the xts index, you could e.g. do `idx <- which(strftime(index(z), "%H:%M:%S")=="05:00:00"); z2 <- z[idx]`. I don't know if it's the xts way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `split` your data by HH:MM:SS, then loop over the resulting list.

```
# convert to factor because split.xts will pass f to endpoints() if f is character
# (even if it's more than one element). split.zoo is called if f is factor.
y <- split(z, factor(format(index(z), "%H%M%S")))
# loop over each time group
l <- lapply(y, FUN)
# combine results
x <- do.call(rbind, l)
```